# Open Link in New Tab in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use a Button to open a link in a new tab in ASP.NET. I'm trying the following but it isn't working:

```
<asp:Button ID="ReportButton" runat="server" CssClass="button" Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="White" Text="Report" OnClick="ReportButton_Click" OnClientClick="form1.target='_blank';" />
```

In the code, `ReportButton_Click` is defined as follows:

```
protected void SkidPackReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GoToPage(LocationSkidPackReportPage);
}
```

and `GoToPage` is defined as follows:

```
bool GoToPage(string page)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Redirect(page);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "There was an error finding the page.";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot post back to server and open a new tab/window. Browser's popup blocker will block the window. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the error shown ??

Answer (score 3):

Don't do server-side `Response.Redirect`, just do a client-side `window.open`. E.g.

```
void GoToPage(string page) {

  ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this, this.GetType(), "newPage", String.Format("window.open({0});", page), True);

}
```

Or better yet - avoid postback altogether. You can assign `clientClick` to your button like:

```
ReportButton.OnClientClick = String.Format("window.open({0});return false;", LocationSkidPackReportPage);
```

This way new page will be opened on client without need to go back to the server.

Comment: Where exactly should I put that in order for it to work?

Comment: If you use first version - it just replaces your original `GoToPage` function. If you go with second - you have to put where `LocationSkidPackReportPage` value changes

Answer (score 1):

Make `LocationSkidPackReportPage` a public property in code behind and then replace your button by:

```
<a href="<%=LocationSkidPackReportPage%>" class="button" target="_blank">Report</a>
```

OR, if you need to fill this var in code behind:

```
// Response.Redirect(page); -> Replace this by:

string script = String.Format("window.open('{0}', '_blank');", LocationSkidPackReportPage);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(this, this.GetType(), "reportResultPage", script, True);
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
   this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('../_Reportes/ReporteGeneral.aspx','_newtab');", true);
```

Comment: You should explain any code that you post in your answer; the idea is to help the asker so that he understands __how__ the problem is solved, rather than simply taking the solution with him/her.